# MySQL Joining 3 Tables Not Returning All Results

Tags: mysql, sql, tags, relational-database, left-join

## The Goal

Properly join 3 tables to create a list view for quickly identifying who created the tag, when, and how many times it is being used.

---

## Table Design

Table: `tags`

```
 id    tag        type        submitted_on            submitted_by
------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    tag1       type1       0000-00-00 00:00:00      1
  2    tag2       type1       0000-00-00 00:00:00      1
  3    tag3       type1       0000-00-00 00:00:00      1
  4    tag4       type1       0000-00-00 00:00:00      1
  5    tag5       type1       0000-00-00 00:00:00      1
```

Table: `tagmap`

```
 id    tag        type        tl    users    comms    events    submitted_on           submitted_by
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      1        type1        2        0        0         0    0000-00-00 00:00:00    1
  2      1        type1      156        0        0         0    0000-00-00 00:00:00    1
  3      2        type1        2        0        0         0    0000-00-00 00:00:00    1
  4      3        type1        2        0        0         0    0000-00-00 00:00:00    1
```

Table: `users`

```
 id    first      last
-----------------------
  1    John       Doe
```

---

## The Query

```
SELECT
        tags.id AS tagid,
        tags.tag,
        tags.submitted_on AS date,
        CONCAT(users.first, ' ', users.last) AS username,
        count(tm.tl) AS tls,
        count(tm.user) AS users,
        count(tm.comm) AS comms,
        count(tm.event) AS events
    FROM tags
        LEFT JOIN users
            ON users.id = tags.submitted_by
        LEFT JOIN tagmap AS tm
            ON tags.id = tm.tag
            GROUP BY tm.tag
        ORDER BY tags.id ASC
```

---

## The Result

```
 tagid    tag     date                   username     tls    users    comms    events
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1    tag1    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       2        0        0         0 
     2    tag2    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       1        0        0         0 
     3    tag3    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       1        0        0         0 
     4    tag4    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       0        0        0         0
```

---

## The EXPECTED Result

```
 tagid    tag     date                   username     tls    users    comms    events
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1    tag1    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       2        0        0         0 
     2    tag2    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       1        0        0         0 
     3    tag3    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       1        0        0         0 
     4    tag4    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       0        0        0         0 
     5    tag5    0000-00-00 00:00:00    John Doe       0        0        0         0
```

---

## The Issue

The query only returns 4 rows when there are 5 `tags` total. Both tag4 and tag5 have no connections, yet tag4 is still returned. I need all `tags` returned, regardless if there are any connections in the `tagmap` table.

---

## The Question

How do I properly write this query to include ALL `tags`, regardless of `tagmap` connections?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY tags.id` ,you are grouping your results by `tagmap`'s  `tag` column which does not has all associations from your tag table

```
SELECT
        tags.id AS tagid,
        tags.tag,
        tags.submitted_on AS date,
        users.id AS userid,
        CONCAT(users.first, ' ', users.last) AS username,
        count(tm.tl) AS tls,
        count(tm.users) AS users,
        count(tm.comms) AS comms,
        count(tm.events) AS events
    FROM tags
        LEFT JOIN users
            ON users.id = tags.submitted_by
        LEFT JOIN tagmap AS tm
            ON tags.id = tm.tag
            GROUP BY tags.id
        ORDER BY tags.id ASC
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45fde/5)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are grouping them according to tag column in table tagmap. Try to change the first tag (eg. 4 not 1) and execute query again. Probably you will get 5 rows as a result.